# Grep with color and multiple excludes

Tags: grep

I would like to do a grep to dig through my code hierarchy and look for the term "x", but color the results and exclude annoying terms.  Right now I do:

```
grep -Rn --color x * | grep -v -e html -e svn -e test -e doc -e y
```

The problem is that this loses the matching color because of the pipe.  Is there anyway to make this one statement so that the coloring isn't lost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify `--color=always` to preserve color formatting through pipes:

```
grep --color=always x * | grep -v -e html -e svn -e test -e doc -e y
```

And later on if you happen to need to pipe the result into a file and need to remove the escape characters that format color, here's a nifty sed script you can pipe your results through to remove the escape charaters:

```
sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g"
```

(Note that you need `-E` option instead of `-r` for OS X)

Comment: Excellent. Do you know if there's a way to set --color-always as a default?  Also, is it possible to do the "This but not those" match without doing a pipe?

Comment: A bit of shameless plug: if you want to set certain flags as "default" so you don't have to type it every time: I wrote a shell tool for grep/ack to use "profiles" that remember your preferred settings. An introduction: http://reviewboardstudents.wordpress.com/2012/10/22/ucosp-blog-post-sack-and-other-developer-shortcuts/ and on github: https://github.com/sampson-chen/sack

Answer (score 1):

You can try repeating the color search:

```
grep -Rn --color x * | grep -v -e html -e svn -e test -e doc -e y | grep --color x
```

Comment: Yah, I did that but the problem is if "x" is in the file path then it highlights that as well.